# SQL query to produce work in progress at a given point in time

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm have a project management database for which I'm attempting to construct a SQL query which will produce the most recent estimate of a given user's work in progress at a given point in time.

Work in progress is defined as a task which, at the given time, its most recent task history is one where the status column is one of the following values: `12,13,14,15`.

An excerpt of the structure and data set is provided below.

For this dataset, the following scenarios apply:

### Scenario 1

- Input parameters:

  - User id: 1
  - Point in time: 2018-01-01
- Should return estimate entry with ID 1

  - Optimistic: 5, Realistic 10, Pessimistic: 20

### Scenario 2

- Input parameters:

  - User id: 1
  - Point in time: 2017-01-01
- Should return estimate entry with ID 4

  - Optimistic: 2, Realistic: 4, Pessimistic: 6

### Scenario 3

- Input parameters

  - User id: 1
  - Point in time: 2017-06-01
- Should return no entries - there were no works in progress for user 1 at this time

### Scenario 4

- Input parameters

  - User id: 2
  - Point in time: 2017-01-01
- Should return no entries - there are no works in progress for user 2 at this time (or any other time, for that matter)

The complexity of this query is way outside of what I usually have to deal with, SQL-wise. I'm therefore looking for advice as to how to structure the query. Please advise if I should request this type of assistance elsewhere.

```
# Dump of table estimate
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `estimate`;

CREATE TABLE `estimate` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `task_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `optimistic` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `realistic` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `pessimistic` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOCK TABLES `estimate` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `estimate` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `estimate` (`id`, `task_id`, `optimistic`, `realistic`, `pessimistic`, `created`)
VALUES
    (1,1,5,10,20,'2017-10-01 00:00:00'),
    (2,1,10,20,30,'2018-02-01 00:00:00'),
    (3,2,1,2,3,'2016-10-01 00:00:00'),
    (4,2,2,4,6,'2016-11-01 00:00:00'),
    (5,2,3,6,0,'2017-01-01 00:00:00');

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `estimate` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;


# Dump of table task
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `task`;

CREATE TABLE `task` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOCK TABLES `task` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `task` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `task` (`id`, `user_id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1,1,'WIP 2018-01-01'),
    (2,1,'WIP 2017-01-01');

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `task` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;


# Dump of table task_history
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `task_history`;

CREATE TABLE `task_history` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `task_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOCK TABLES `task_history` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `task_history` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `task_history` (`id`, `task_id`, `status`, `timestamp`)
VALUES
    (1,1,10,'2017-10-01 00:00:00'),
    (2,1,12,'2017-12-01 00:00:00'),
    (3,1,1,'2018-01-03 00:00:00'),
    (4,2,10,'2016-10-01 00:00:00'),
    (5,2,14,'2016-12-01 00:00:00'),
    (6,2,1,'2017-02-01 00:00:00');

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `task_history` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;


# Dump of table user
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOCK TABLES `user` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `user` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1,'User 1'),
    (2,'User 2');

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `user` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: The best thing for help, give us sample data (You can use sqlfiddle for an even nicer experience), and let us know of your expected output. We can then work on queries, and try to mimic the results. Also, hi Strawberry

Comment: I suspect most people here would prefer SHOW CREATE TABLE statements over DESCRIBEstatements. Well, I know I would. Also, and related to the above, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the tips! I had some trouble with sqlfiddle (it complains about "access denied") so I updated the post to include create and insert statements.

Comment: Why are estimate.ids 3, 4, and 5 excluded from the result in scenario 1?

Comment: Because they belong to task ID 2 which was not WIP at that point in time (ref task_history).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Estimate, TaskHistory
WHERE Estimate.task_id = TaskHistory.task_id
AND status IN (12,13,14,15);
```

This should select the estimate(s) where its corresponding TaskHistory has status that's either 12, 13, 14 or 15.

Comment: I think we tend to discourage a style that was effectively deprecated in 1992.

Comment: @Strawberry would joins be well suited here instead?

Comment: This is a join; it's just written in implicit/comma style

Comment: This does not solve my problem. I've added scenarios to the original post to (hopefully) make the problem more clear.

Comment: @EirikA.Johansen oh of course it doesn't, because I never thought of timestamp back then, do you still need help with it?

Comment: Yes. I do not belive I have received a valid answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

The following query gets the most recent task history record for each task for each user before a given point in time `@timestamp`.

It then only returns the rows that have the statuses of interest for you.

```
select th.*
from task_history th join
     task t
     on th.task_id = t.task_id
where th.timestamp = (select max(th2.timestamp)
                      from task_history th2 join
                           task t2
                           on th2.task_id = t.task_id
                      where t2.assignee_id = t.assignee_id and
                            th2.timestamp <= @timestamp
                     ) and
      th.status in (12, 13, 14, 15);
```

I suspect that you want additional filtering (for a particular user) or perhaps aggregation.  Your question is unclear on what the result set should look like.

Comment: I've added scenarios to my original question in an attempt at making it more clear with the result set should look like.

Comment: @EirikA.Johansen . . . I think you can easily adapt this answer by adjust `@timestamp` and adding a filter for a particular user.

Comment: It's now clear to me how, as what I'm looking for in the result is the estimate, and not the task_history. Also, the query does not seem to take into account selecting the most recent estimate at the time of `@timestamp`.